# Event based programming, how to respond to instance which sent request

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, delegates

I have a function which performs a long running operation. The function is accessed by many forms/classes of my application. When the operation is completed it calls an event to which many instances of different forms are bound.

How can I avoid the event calling all the functions bound to it. I want to instead pass some variable/UUID from client forms when calling the function which can be then used to invoke only that specific instance of class/form.

There are multiple threads operating on the function.

```
class MyClass: IMyInterface
{
    public event ObjectReceivedDelegate PriceResponse;
    MyClass()
    {
    }
    public void GetPrice(List<string> symbols)
    {
        //Call a long running function from a service in a background thread
    }
    void GetPricesAsync_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        PriceResponse(e.Result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us enough code to be able to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: I think the scenario is easily understood for anyone who has worked on the event based programming approach. Though I have added the code now.

Comment: Give every potential recipient its own instance of MyClass.

Comment: actually it is implementing an interface

Comment: That does not seem to matter. But the problem is in how you manage and bind to objects, not in the event handling.

Comment: The class is one of my common service class which is implemented through a service interface so I can not create new instances for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass Action to your function. like

```
void SomeFunc(Action a)
{
  // your code
  a.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: My class is implementing a interface (not a service) and is in the same application as the caller class. Can I invoke the delegate in this scenario also.

Comment: @puneet and you can't change Interface?
`public void GetPrice(List<string> symbols, Action<TypeOfResult> a)
    {
        //Call a long running function from a service in a background thread
        a.Invoke(Result);
    }`